# MVC 4 Retrieve db id from newly created entry

Tags: mysql, sql, database, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

If I create a entry in a database such as this (cvmCasefile has all info needed to create the casefile):

```
Casefile casefile = cvm.Casefile;
casefile.ClientId = cvm.Client.ClientId;
casefile.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;

db.Casefiles.Add(casefile);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Immediately after the save call I try to retrieve this entries ID number from the database with:

```
int casefileId = db.Casefiles.Where(u => u.UserProfileId == casefile.UserProfileId)
                             .Where(c => c.ClientId == casefile.ClientId)
                             .Single(d => d.DateSubmitted == casefile.DateSubmitted).CasefileId;
```

This returns null when it is executed. I've stepped through the program and all casefile values are populated and the database has the required row inserted with a valid ID#. Is there an easier way to get the ID from the database or where did is screw-up the call to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you may just do

```
var id = casefile.CasefileId;
```

after the `SaveChanges`

Comment: sometimes the obvious is so simple. Thought I tried it but must not have. Thanks